# mclapply not using multiple cores

Tags: r

I'm trying to process a bunch of csv files and return data frames in R, in parallel using `mclapply()`. I have a 64 core machine, and I can't seem to get anymore that 1 core utilized at the moment using `mclapply()`. In fact, it is a bit quicker to run `lapply()` rather than `mclapply()` at the moment. Here is an example that shows that mclapply() is not utilizing more the cores available:

```
library(parallel)

test <- lapply(1:100,function(x) rnorm(10000))
system.time(x <- lapply(test,function(x) loess.smooth(x,x)))
system.time(x <- mclapply(test,function(x) loess.smooth(x,x), mc.cores=32))

user  system elapsed
  0.000   0.000   7.234
user  system elapsed
  0.000   0.000   8.612
```

Is there some trick to getting this working? I had to compile R from source on this machine (v3.0.1), are there some compile flags that I missed to allow forking? `detectCores()` tells me that I indeed do have 64 cores to play with...
 Any tips appreciated!

Comment: What OS are you using? It doesn't seem relevant to your case, but it is worth noting that `mclapply` on Windows is just a wrapper for `lapply`.

Comment: Linux. Redhat to be precise.

Comment: If anyone can verify that the above example actually does speed up with mclapply() that would also help.

Comment: Works (faster) for me on Mac OS X. What does running `ulimit -n` in a terminal session tell you? Is something in your OS / session limiting the number of cores you can use? Are you running R within a GUI, or from a terminal?

Comment: I just tried it myself on OsX and also got a speed up.

Comment: ulimit -n gives me 1024. I'm running as a script with "Rscript test.R"

Comment: works from me on ubuntu 64bit, R-2.15.3 and R-3.0.1

Comment: So what could possibly be blocking R from creating new forks in RHEL?

Answer (score 6):

I get similar results to you, but if I change `rnorm(10000)` to `rnorm(100000)`, I get significant speed up.  I would guess that the additional overhead is canceling out any performance benefit for such a small scale problem.